# three20 datasource and table issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

Why am I getting the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[TTTableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:5678
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

How do I fix this?

the point where it stops is:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews]; //right here
```

this is inside TTTableView.m

Comment: The delegate call back to get the table view cell can not be nil.

Comment: this is Three20 and RestKit, are you aware of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

There's your answer. You must be returning a cell. Either your datasource isn't set or tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: isn't returning anything.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I am using the implementation https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Code/Three20/RKObjectTTTableViewDataSource.m and it doesn't seem to have a cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using RestKit + Three20 to populate a TTTableViewController with CoreData objects.

Turns out that the `RKObjectManager`'s `objectStore` property wasn't set properly. I fixed it in the App initialization then the TTTableViewController was populated successfully.